# what does "Owner" field in packer "source_ami_filter" work on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

i am  new packer and exploring few things on it while using it something like this came up

```
"builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "profile" : "sumanthdev",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
          "virtualization-type": "hvm",
          "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*",
          "root-device-type": "ebs"
        },
        "owners": ["099720109477"],
        "most_recent": true
      },
```

I want to know what "owners": ["099720109477"], stands for .
i know it takes input of an account id , but which ? the account id where it going to create the ami , or?

Answer (score 2):

This is to filter the AMIs, for those that are owned by a specific AWS account. In this case this filter will only find images owned by the account id of `099720109477` that are named `ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*`.

Below from the [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon/ebs/#owners)

> Filters the images by their owner. You may specify one or more AWS account IDs, "self" (which will use the account whose credentials you are using to run Packer), or an AWS owner alias: for example, amazon, aws-marketplace, or microsoft. This option is required for security reasons.

Comment: thank you for the answer . It did come up in the research i was doing .
What if i don't have a owners account ID and i want to get latest Linux image ?

Comment: You won't be able to get the image if you do not have the account id according to docs

Comment: than you . could you help me out with this question as well 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321422/not-able-to-fine-packer-built-image-in-the-console

Answer (score 1):

"099720109477 is the account number for Canonical." [Source](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5026#issuecomment-309840770). (The comment below that one is also quite useful.)

Note that `owners` is also an [optional parameter](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon/ebs#optional-3).

You may be looking for the `ami_users` field in order to share the AMI across accounts.  `ami_users` is not a parameter in the `source_ami_filter` but instead can be found in the top-level of the `source` body, like so:

```
source "amazon-ebs" "dev-latest" {
  ami_name      = "dev-latest-${local.timestamp}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  region        = var.region
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      image-id            = "ami-03d5c68bab01f3496"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
    }
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["099720109477"]
  }
  ssh_username = "ubuntu"
  ami_users = ["777777777777", "888888888888", "999999999999"]
}
```

`owners` own the base AMI (layer) of the AMI you are making.  `ami_users` are account numbers that the completed image is shared with.  After the AMI is "Available", you'll see output (at least with packer) that indicates it is modifying the privacy attributes of the completed image.