# Not able to fine packer built image in the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am new to packer and i am trying my hands on it.

```
{

  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "profile" : "sumanthdev",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
          "virtualization-type": "hvm",
          "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*",
          "root-device-type": "ebs"
        },
        "owners": ["099720109477"],
        "most_recent": true
      },
      "instance_type": "t2.micro",
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
      "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp}}"
    }
  ]

}
```

which gave me an out put

==> Builds finished. The artifacts of successful builds are:
--> amazon-ebs: AMIs were created:
us-east-1: ami-0b9dfb74858d0f690

when i log into to console i am not able to see the ami in my console.

Note : i am using my profile "sumanthdev" which is set up in my aws.cerdentials file

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Can you check CloudTrail to confirm the API call occured?

Comment: Look in the correct region.

Comment: I don't see any activity in cloud trail log . @mokugo-devops

Comment: I am checking in the right region @jarmod

Comment: It'll take about 15 minutes after you do it. Do you have a filter on your AMI screen perhaps?

Comment: Do you have multiple AWS accounts? Are you looking in the wrong AWS account?